# Bayes Decision and Bayes Error, Probabilistic pattern recognition

Tags: probability, bayesian, integral

Consider a classification problem where $X = (X1, X2) \in R2$ is uniform in $[- 1, 1] × [- 1, 1]$, and
the conditional probability of Y = 1 is given by $\eta(x^1,x^2) = \frac{1}{4}(x^1 + 1)(x^2 + 1)$. We denote the components of a vector by $x^1. x^2, ...$ to distinguish them from (possibly multidimensional) data points $x_1, x_2, ...$

Task: Compute the Bayes Decision and Bayes error for this problem.

My solution is the following:

$\phi_(x^*)= 
    \begin{cases}
        \;\ 1 & \text{if } \;\,\eta > \frac{1}{2}\\
        -1 & \text{otherwise }  \\
    \end{cases}$
}

\begin{equation}
 \\ \\    \frac{1}{4}(x^1 +1)(x^2 +1) > \frac{1}{2} \;\ <=> \;\
    x^2 > \frac{1 - x^1}{1 + x^1}
\end{equation}

We have a Uniform distribution [-1,1] for each variable $x^1, x^2$. The corresponding pdf is $\frac{1}{1 - (-1)} = \frac{1}{2}$. So the probability that both variables occur in the region where $P( Y = 1 ) $  is = $\frac{1}{2} * \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{4}$

\begin{equation}
 P(Y = 1) = \int_{0}^{1} \int_{\frac{1-x^1}{1 + x^1}}^{1} \frac{1}{4}d x^2 d x^1 =  \frac{1}{4} \int_{0}^{1} 1 - \frac{1 - x^1}{x^1 + 1}dx^1 = \frac{1}{4}(2 - 2ln2) = \frac{1}{2} - \frac{ln2}{2}
\end{equation}

Bayes Error:
\begin{equation}
 \\  P(Y != 1) = 1 - P(Y=1) = 1 - (\frac{1}{2} - \frac{ln2}{2}) = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{ln2}{2}
\end{equation}

However it does not seem to be a correct solution.

Could some, please, provide the explanation of how to approach this task?

Comment: I would start by using clearer notations and definitions.  In particular, it would help almost all readers to stipulate that $Y$ is a Bernoulli variable and the conditioning is on $(X_1,X_2).$ The use of superscripts is jarring in a context where it's likely powers will crop up: that just adds to the conceptual burden of your audience, especially because you never do need to refer to "multidimensional data points" anyway.